# "Cannot convert parameter from '[classname](_cdecl *)(void)' to '[classname]'" error when constructing an object

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constructor

Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

There are two important classes here, Date and Directory.

```
class Date
{
private:
    int month, day, year;
public:
    Date();
    Date(int month, int day, int year);
};

class Directory : public [Superclass]
{
private:
    File* fileContents[50];
    Directory* dirContents[5];
public:
    Directory();
    Directory(char* name, 
        long size, 
        Date dateCreated, 
        Date dateModified,
        Date dateAccessed,
        int attributes);
};
```

I defined the constructors farther down - the `Date` constructor works just like you think it does. Now, I'm **really** new to C++, so I can't even comprehend the error messages I'm getting. If I try to use the default constructor for `Directory`, I get this error message:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class Directory __cdecl d(void)" (?d@@YA?AVDirectory@@XZ) referenced in function _main
```

If I try to make it by using 3 `Date` objects, with this code:

```
int main()
{
    Date d1();
    Date d2();
    Date d3();
    Directory d("Hello", 12, d1, d2, d3, 0);
    cout << d;
}
```

These are my error messages:

```
error C2664: 'Directory::Directory(char *,long,Date,Date,Date,int)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'Date (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'Date'
```

IntelliSense: `no instance of constructor "Directory::Directory" matches the argument list`

EDIT: So, in a continuing effort to make zero sense to me, VS has decided to compile my program fine when the three `Date` arguments are created with `Date da[3]` and the arguments for the constructor are `("Hello", 12, d[0], d[1], d[2], 0)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the standard

> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (),
>   shall be value-initialized.
>
> [Note: since () is not permitted by the syntax for initializer,
>
> X a ();
>
> is not the declaration of an object of class X, but the
>   declaration of a function taking no argument and returning an X. The
>   form () is permitted in certain other initialization contexts (5.3.4,
>   5.2.3, 12.6.2). —end note ]

So, you need to change your declarations as follows

```
int main()
{
    Date d1;
    Date d2;
    Date d3;
    Directory d("Hello", 12, d1, d2, d3, 0);
    cout << d;
}
```

Comment: So it should be Date d1; instead?

Comment: Okay, thanks. Out of curiosity, in what circumstance would I want to do Date d1(); ?

Comment: @GaiusOctavian, good question, I'll try to find more information about it.

Comment: @GaiusOctavian, when `d1` is a function returning `Date`

Answer (score 3):

C++ has a rather irritating corner case when it comes to variable declarations.

The following is legal C++:

```
int main() {
    int foo(int x);
    return foo(42);
}
```

It simply sets up a declaration of a function named `foo` in the scope of `main`. For the program to run, `foo` will need to be defined somewhere, or you will get a link error.

Now, consider

```
Date foo();
```

This is the syntax for a forward declaration of a function `foo` taking no arguments and returning a `Date` object. But, `Date foo(42);` is a declaration of a variable `foo` of type `Date` initialized with a single integer as an argument. Your compiler normally figures out if you wanted a variable or a function based on whether the argument is a type or an expression, but in the zero-argument case (the default constructor), the compiler can't tell and therefore *defaults to the function declaration* (since the standard says so).

So, by writing

```
Directory d();
```

you forward-declared a function `d` taking nothing and returning `Directory`. When you link the program, you get an error saying that the function `class Directory __cdecl d(void)` (a function called `d` taking nothing and returning a `Directory`) is not defined, since C++ only saw a forward declaration of this function.

To solve this, in C++, writing

```
Directory d;
```

will create a variable of type `Dictionary` and initialize it with the default constructor.