# Call constructor inside a call to another constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

Suppose I have classes A, B:

```
class A
{
    int a;
public:

    A(int a) : a(a) { }
};

class B
{
    A a;
public:

    B(A a) : a(a) { }
};
```

And I want to create an instance of B as:

```
int i = 1;
B b(A(i));
```

But when I actually try to use b, I get the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533172/cannot-convert-parameter-from-classname-cdecl-void-to-classname-e). That is, b is not an instance of B, it's a function that returns an object of type B. However, it's a different case from the linked question, and I can't figure out why it's happening here.

I could create B as:

```
int i = 1;
A a(i);
B b(a);
```

Or even as:

```
B b(A(1));
```

And it'll work. However, in the real case the first option requires too many lines, and the second option requires very long line (because instead of int I have an object which needs to be constructed, and I have a chain of some objects). How can I create the int in his own line, and then create A and B in the same line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **problem** is that `B b(A(i));` is a function declaration and not a declaration for a variable named `b` of type `B`.

This is due to what is called [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). In particular, the statement:

```
B b(A(i)); //this is a declaration for a function named `b` that takes parameter of type A and has no return type
```

the above is a **declaration** for a function named `b` that takes one parameter of type `A` and with return type of `B`.

To solve this, you can either use curly braces `{}` or double `()` to solve this:

##### Method 1

Use `{}` around `A(i)`.

```
//----v----v------->declares a variable of type B and is not a function declaration
   B b{A(i)};
```

##### Method 2

Use double parenthesis `(())`.

```
//-v--------v------>declares a variable of type B and is not a function declaration
B b( (A(i)) );
```

Answer (score 2):

One obvious way to rule out any possible function declaration is:

```
B b { A {i} };
```